# How do I make the most use of MongoDB and Redis Caching for a high scalable application?

Tags: mongodb, caching, redis, scalable

I want to use the best features of Redis Caching and Mongo DB database for my current product. 
I have a very heavy database, and would like to avoid multiple database calls.

Can I cache my documents in Redis and do a query instead?

What level caching would be suggested for the best performance?

Comment: Your question is too abstract, Learn about redis and mongodb. search for some samples, how people have solved heavy problems (handling millions inserts in a sec etc). Do some coding, then comeback and ask a precise question we are happy to help you out.

Comment: do you consider any alternatives to Redis for caching?

Comment: In general: Whenusing MongoDB, you model for optimized performance of your use cases, not by ERM. Other than that, I can only second @KarthikeyanGopall: You question is too abstract! Give sample documents, describe the problems you are facing and we might find a solution without adding a moving part.